# can someone please explain this Archimedean sphere surface area?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, spheres

If a polygon be inscribed in a segment of a circle LAL' so that all its sides
excluding the base are equal and their number even, as LK ... A ...K'L',
A being the middle point of the segment; and if the lines BB', CC',...
parallel to the base LL' and joining pairs of angular points be drawn, then
(BB'+ CC'+..+ LM):AM = A'B:BA, where M is the middle point of
LL' and AA' is the diameter through M [Fig. 6.6].

This is the geometric equivalent of the trigonometric equation

$$sin\frac {\theta}n +sin \frac{2\theta}n + ... sin\frac{n-1}n\theta + \frac12 sin\frac {n \theta}n= \frac{1-cos\theta}2cot\frac{\theta}{2n} $$

[image]

Comment: Do you have an explicit mathematical question? "Can someone please explain" is not a mathematical question.

Comment: Actually i am reading a math history book and stuck at this phrase. I can't understand what he is comparing here. Is it lines or angles?  (BB'+ CC'+..+ LM):AM = A'B:BA,

Comment: Also how does the trignometry equation relate to this polygon in the image